# What is a recursive algorithm to calculate number of edges in a 3- dimensional i-j-k grid graphs?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, grid

The final solution would be equal to `(i-1)jk + (k-1)ij + (j-1)ki`. My idea is to create a function that would calculate number of edges parallel to either axis `i, j, k`. Suppose we call function to calculate edges parallel to axis i by `calc_i`.

```
calc_i(i,j,k):

if(k==1)
   return i(j-1)+j(i-1)

return calc_i(i,j,k-1)+calc_i(i,j,1)
```

We could call other function that counts edges parallel to axis j and k by simply changing the i,j,k input parameters to function calc_i and call it by another function calc_total

```
calc_total(i,j,k):

return (calc_i(i,j,k) + calc_i(j,k,i) + calc_i(k,i,j))/2
```

Then, after calling three functions we would get the result `k(i(j-1)+j(i-1)) + j(i(k-1)+k(i-1))+i(j(k-1)+k(j-1))`. Dividing the final result by two we would eventually get the desired answer.

Question: Is there a possible way to combine those three functions `calc_i ,calc_j ,calc_k` into a single, neat recursive function that would give the same result as above?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question I've to say yes you could with something like this:

```
calc(i,j,k)

    if(i == 1) 
        return k(j-1)+j(k-1)
    if(j == 1) 
        return k(i-1)+i(k-1)
    if(k == 1) 
        return i(j-1)+j(i-1)

    a = calc(i,j,k-1)+calc(i,j,1)
    b = calc(i,j,k-1)+calc(i,j,1)
    c = calc(i,j,k-1)+calc(i,j,1)

    return a+b+c
```

But I'm not found of your approach at all!